# Drop consecutive duplicates on specific columns pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to remove consecutive duplicates within a subset of columns from the dataframe. I found a solution on how to do it but only for single columns [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52146821/drop-consecutive-duplicates-in-a-pyspark-dataframe)

Having a dataframe like this:

```
test_df = spark.createDataFrame([
  (2,3.0,"a", "2020-01-01"),
  (2,6.0,"a", "2020-01-02"),
  (3,2.0,"a", "2020-01-02"),
  (4,1.0,"b", "2020-01-04"),
  (4,9.0,"b", "2020-01-05"),
  (4,7.0,"b", "2020-01-05"),
  (2,3.0,"a", "2020-01-08"),
  (4,7.0,"b", "2020-01-09")
], ("id", "num","st", "date"))

##############
id   num   st    date
2,   3.0,  "a"  "2020-01-01"
2,   6.0,  "a"  "2020-01-02"
3,   2.0,  "a"  "2020-01-02"
4,   1.0,  "b"  "2020-01-04"
4,   9.0,  "b"  "2020-01-05"
4,   7.0,  "b"  "2020-01-05"
2,   3.0,  "a"  "2020-01-08"
4,   7.0,  "b"  "2020-01-09"
```

I want to remove consecutive duplicates in an specific set of columns [id,st] keeping the first record (ordered by date) when consecutive cases appear. If two samples appear on same day and cant be properly ordered it can be choosen at random. The result would look like:

```
##############
id   num   st    date
2,   3.0,  "a"   "2020-01-01"
3,   2.0,  "a"   "2020-01-02"
4,   1.0,  "b"   "2020-01-04"
2,   3.0,  "a"   "2020-01-08"
4,   7.0,  "b"   "2020-01-09"
```

How could I do that?

Comment: what is the rule to order the lines? i believe you keep the first the record but how do you define the proper order ?

Comment: @Steven yes first record, sr I didn't explicitly mentioned it. Edited the main post

Comment: this kind of operation has already been answered several times. Here is one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68076603/aggregate-over-time-windows-on-a-partitioned-grouped-by-window/68086351#68086351

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Aggregate over time windows on a partitioned/grouped by window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68076603/aggregate-over-time-windows-on-a-partitioned-grouped-by-window)

Comment: I'm not able to use your code sample. In theory it seems like it should work for this use case as well but when creating the ID column all my rows are labeled as id=1. When running the last df4 code then it wont be the expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concat these columns `id` and `st` and verify if the previous value is the same as the current using `lag` function.

```py
from pyspark.sql import Window

import pyspark.sql.functions as f

window = Window.orderBy(f.col('date'))
before_dedup_df = (test_df
                   .withColumn('_custom_id', f.concat(f.col('id'), f.col('st')))
                   .withColumn('_consecutive', f.col('_custom_id').eqNullSafe(f.lag('_custom_id').over(window))))
# +---+---+---+----------+----------+------------+
# |id |num|st |date      |_custom_id|_consecutive|
# +---+---+---+----------+----------+------------+
# |2  |3.0|a  |2020-01-01|2a        |false       |
# |2  |6.0|a  |2020-01-02|2a        |true        |
# |3  |2.0|a  |2020-01-02|3a        |false       |
# |4  |1.0|b  |2020-01-04|4b        |false       |
# |4  |9.0|b  |2020-01-05|4b        |true        |
# |4  |7.0|b  |2020-01-05|4b        |true        |
# |2  |3.0|a  |2020-01-08|2a        |false       |
# |4  |7.0|b  |2020-01-09|4b        |false       |
# +---+---+---+----------+----------+------------+

dedup_df = (before_dedup_df
            .where(~f.col('_consecutive'))
            .drop('_custom_id', '_consecutive'))
# +---+---+---+----------+
# |id |num|st |date      |
# +---+---+---+----------+
# |2  |3.0|a  |2020-01-01|
# |3  |2.0|a  |2020-01-02|
# |4  |1.0|b  |2020-01-04|
# |2  |3.0|a  |2020-01-08|
# |4  |7.0|b  |2020-01-09|
# +---+---+---+----------+
```